# Extracting function arguments from function having space after function name using Perl

Tags: regex, perl

After searching for functions in a C file using regex in Perl, I want to extract its arguments.

MY CODE

```
... #after searching for functions
if ($src_line1 =~ /^ \S+ \s+ (\S+) \s* (\( .+? \)) /xsmg) { 
        my @args = $2 =~ /(\w+)[,)]/g;                      #extracts function arguments
```

But my code works for function like:

```
int abc(int i, int j)
```

But doesn't work for function:

```
int xyz (int k, int l)        #having space after function name
```

Can anyone help me how to make it work for both cases?

Comment: You an add `( ?)` to capture a single potential space or use (\s*) for more than one

Comment: Looks to me like it should work because of `\s*` in the regexp.

Comment: Yes, I just tested it, it works http://regex101.com/r/gN1zZ8

Comment: then why is it not working for me? okay thanks for the help. I will debug my code further to check for any other error

Comment: @Ad-vic, it seems you have been trying to write regex-based parsers for C for *months* now. This is suboptimal for a variety of reasons, so don't you think that writing or adapting a proper parser would pay off in the long run? Static analysis of C code is a common problem, and many solutions already exist. There is also a fair share of C parsers on CPAN.

Comment: Note that `if (/.../g)` doesn't make any sense and can give some very surprising results. Get rid of that `g`!

Comment: Be aware that there are many ways of formatting function definitions, and there may be all sorts of 'junk' in there. As a not-too-nice example: `static inline char const *(function)(int (*handler)(void), const char *str)` could be the start of a legitimate inline function.  It is far from unheard of for the return type information to be on a line preceding the function name, nor for a function with many parameters to have them spread over many lines. You can/should experiment with what you're doing, but be aware that you've got a lot of work ahead of you if you plan to make it fully reliable.

Comment: i understand its not yet reliable. I should use c parser already available. But right now i need to fix this issue as i already have put lot of time into it

Answer (score 1):

Your code does work:

```
$ cat cparser.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my @src_lines = ("int abc(int i, int j)",
                 "int xyz (int k, int l)");

foreach my $line (@src_lines) {
    my @args = ();
    if ($line =~ /^ \S+ \s+ (\S+) \s* (\( .+? \)) /xsmg) {
        @args = ($2 =~ /(\w+)[,)]/g);
    }
    printf "%-25s %s\n", $line, (join ", ", @args);
}

$ perl cparser.pl
int abc(int i, int j)     i, j
int xyz (int k, int l)    k, l
```

However, it might be wise to look in to existing parsers, be it Perl or otherwise. Use your time to integrate an existing parser into your project, instead of re-inventing the wheel.