# searching for function definitions name from a list

Tags: regex, perl

i have function names in a text file

i am using it to search function definition names in a C file using Perl

CODE I used

```
#checks whether it has ; present in which case it becomes function declaration
if ($src_line =~ /$func\([^;]+$/)
```

This works for only function definitions of type

```
int foo(int a, int b)
```

But doesn't work for function:

```
int bar (int c, int d)        #having space after function name
```

How do i make it work for both cases.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extracting function arguments from function having space after function name using Perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20829968/extracting-function-arguments-from-function-having-space-after-function-name-usi)

Comment: no its not duplicate.. the question here asks how to find function definitions name and in that question I had asked how to extract function arguments after we get function definitions names.

Comment: I could have merge both question into 1. But I didn't know where my problem was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then, just add `\s*` (meaning: 0 space or more) to your expression:

```
/$func\s*\([^;]+$/
```